# How is subscript computed for OP_CHECKMULTISIG?

Tags: script, protocol, multi-signature, checksig

I'm trying to learn the Bitcoin protocol by implementing it, and I've got `OP_CHECKSIG` working (following instructions in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG), but I can't get an transaction input using `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` to pass signature verification.

Specifically, I'm stuck with the second tx_input of transaction [eb3b82c0884e3efa6d8b0be55b4915eb20be124c9766245bcc7f34fdac32bccb](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/eb3b82c0884e3efa6d8b0be55b4915eb20be124c9766245bcc7f34fdac32bccb), and I suspect that the culprit is subscript (the one to replace signature script in current transaction).

Here's how subscript is computed in my implementation.

First, generate the script by concatenating `[sigScript][OP_CODESEPARATOR][pubkeyScript]` (I understand that script execution has evolved from this).

So a (parsed) script for the input would be like this:

`Frame 00: 0(00)
Frame 01: 
0000 - 30 44 02 20 27 6d 6d ad 3d ef a3 7b 5f 81 ad d3 
0010 - 99 2d 51 0d 2f 44 a3 17 fd 85 e0 4f 93 a1 e2 da 
0020 - ea 64 66 02 02 20 0f 86 2a 0d a6 84 24 93 22 ce 
0030 - b8 ed 84 2f b8 c8 59 c0 cb 94 c8 1e 1c 53 08 b4 
0040 - 86 81 57 a4 28 ee 01 END 
Frame 02: OP_CODESEPARATOR(0xab)
Frame 03: 1(0x51)
Frame 04: 
0000 - 02 32 ab dc 89 3e 7f 06 31 36 4d 7f d0 1c b3 3d 
0010 - 24 da 45 32 9a 00 35 7b 3a 78 86 21 1a b4 14 d5 
0020 - 5a END 
Frame 05: 1(0x51)
Frame 06: OP_CHECKMULTISIG(0xae)
Frame 07: OP_CODESEPARATOR(0xab)
Frame 08: 
0000 - 2a 9b c5 44 7d 66 4c 1d 01 41 39 2a 84 2d 23 db 
0010 - a4 5c 4f 13 END 
Frame 09: OP_NOP2/OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY(0xb1)
Frame 10: OP_DROP(0x75)`

Then, I create the subscript from the closest `OP_CODESEPARATOR` before the `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` that I am executing till the end of the script. So, I include Frame 03 to Frame 10.

Then, I remove other `OP_CODESEPARATOR`s in the script, which is Frame 07.

That means these frames should compose the subscript:

`Frame 03: 1(0x51)
Frame 04: 
0000 - 02 32 ab dc 89 3e 7f 06 31 36 4d 7f d0 1c b3 3d 
0010 - 24 da 45 32 9a 00 35 7b 3a 78 86 21 1a b4 14 d5 
0020 - 5a END 
Frame 05: 1(0x51)
Frame 06: OP_CHECKMULTISIG(0xae)
Frame 08: 
0000 - 2a 9b c5 44 7d 66 4c 1d 01 41 39 2a 84 2d 23 db 
0010 - a4 5c 4f 13 END 
Frame 09: OP_NOP2/OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY(0xb1)
Frame 10: OP_DROP(0x75)`

Serialized, the final subscript looks like this:

`0000 - 51 21 02 32 ab dc 89 3e 7f 06 31 36 4d 7f d0 1c 
0010 - b3 3d 24 da 45 32 9a 00 35 7b 3a 78 86 21 1a b4 
0020 - 14 d5 5a 51 ae 14 2a 9b c5 44 7d 66 4c 1d 01 41 
0030 - 39 2a 84 2d 23 db a4 5c 4f 13 b1 75`

However, when this subscript is used to replace signature script, and eventually generate hash, the ecdsa_verify function reports that signature verification fails (but the inputs are legal).

Since the same procedure works for `OP_CHECKSIG`, I probably missed something obvious, but I couldn't figure this out reading the original Satoshi code, the current implementation, or Bitcoin Wiki.

If it helps, my code for OP_CHECKMULTISIG is here:
https://github.com/blaesus/tinybtc/blob/checkmultisig/src/script.c#L687

A more simplistic version (using prevTx.pubkeyScript as subscript) doesn't yield valid results either: https://github.com/blaesus/tinybtc/blob/validate/src/script.c#L344

Comment: What are the frames you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main confusion here comes from this :

> First, generate the script by concatenating `[sigScript][OP_CODESEPARATOR][pubkeyScript]`

Then you add :

> I understand that script execution has evolved from this

I'm not sure whether you mean "Builds upon this method" or "Has since changed this method", but if it is the former then this might explain the unexpected results that you're getting.  Hopefully my answer can clear this up.

It's true that for a (relatively) short period Bitcoin's script evaluation was done by the way you mentioned, where a `CODESEPARATOR` was placed between `scriptSig` and `scriptPubkey` then the whole thing was concatenated to form a single script which would be executed, but that was changed rather early on in commit `6ff5f718b6a67797b2b3bab8905d607ad216ee21` which dates to July 31st 2010.

After said change, which introduced a function named `VerifyScript` in `script.cpp` (today the logic is in `interpreter.cpp`), `scriptSig` and `scriptPubkey` are no longer concatenated with a `CODESEPARATOR` between them.  Rather they are executed as **two separate scripts** one after the other, where the stack's contents carries from the first to the second.

The difference is subtle and doesn't really change the flow of *standard* redemptions, but becomes noticable when a `CHECKSIG` operation is done within the `scriptSig`.

Starting from the funding transaction

```
b8fd633e7713a43d5ac87266adc78444669b987a56b3a65fb92d58c2c4b0e84d
```

we see that the second output in it is a payment to the following `scriptPubKey` at index `1` :

```
14 2a9bc5447d664c1d0141392a842d23dba45c4f13
NOP2
DROP
```

`OP_CLTV` is not active yet, so the opcode `0xb1` is still `NOP2`.

Which is then redeemed by

```
eb3b82c0884e3efa6d8b0be55b4915eb20be124c9766245bcc7f34fdac32bccb
```

by the input at index `1` :

```
0
47
  30
  44
    02
    20 276d6dad3defa37b5f81add3992d510d2f44a317fd85e04f93a1e2daea646602
    02
    20 0f862a0da684249322ceb8ed842fb8c859c0cb94c81e1c5308b4868157a428ee
  01
CODESEPARATOR
1
21 0232abdc893e7f0631364d7fd01cb33d24da45329a00357b3a7886211ab414d55a
1
CHECKMULTISIG
```

In the short period before commit `6ff5f718`, the two scripts would be concated with a `CODESEPARATOR` placed between them to form the complete script, then execution will start.  We start with an empty stack, and a pointer to the beginning of the script marking the start of what would be the signed `scriptCode` :

1. Push `0` onto the stack
2. Push the signature onto the stack
3. Execute `CODESEPARATOR` - mark this point in the script as the start of `scriptCode` (overwriting the previous value set at the beginning)
4. Push `1` onto the stack
5. Push the pubkey onto the stack
6. Push `1` onto the stack
7. Execute 1-of-1 `CHECKMULTISIG`

At this point, we need to construct the `scriptCode` to be signed.  The rules are :

1. Take the subscript from the last executed `CODESEPARATOR` up until the end of the script
2. Remove all `CODESEPARATORS`
3. Remove all occurences of the signature that is currently being verified

Since the signature is actually *before* the last `CODESEPARATOR`, rule #3 doesn't come into effect here, but rules #1 and #2 do.  This leaves us with the following `scriptCode` :

```
1
21 0232abdc893e7f0631364d7fd01cb33d24da45329a00357b3a7886211ab414d55a
1
CHECKMULTISIG
14 2a9bc5447d664c1d0141392a842d23dba45c4f13
NOP2
DROP
```

Which is what you initially came up with, but now let's see how the change at `6ff5f718` makes a difference.

Recall that we are now dealing with two separate scripts, but none of the other rules change.  The only difference is that these two scripts are executed separately, one after the other, and that the stack that remains from the execution of `scriptSig` passes on to the execution of `scriptPubkey`.

We start by executing `scriptSig` and go through steps #1 - #7 as before, arriving at the same point of `CHECKMULTISIG` where we construct the `scriptCode`.
Since the actual executed script now consists of only what was in `scriptSig`, `scriptCode` becomes :

```
1
21 0232abdc893e7f0631364d7fd01cb33d24da45329a00357b3a7886211ab414d55a
1
CHECKMULTISIG
```

If this signature check passes (and it does), a value of `1` is pushed onto the stack, and `scriptSig` execution ends successfuly.  This stack now passes on to the exectution of `scriptPubkey` (which is very simple) and eventually left as the final value on the stack, which makes `scriptPubkey` resolve to `True`.

This transaction is very interesting really shows how non-trivial commit `6ff5f718` actually was.  It's a great example.

Another minor thing to note is that this `scriptPubKey` by itself is an anyone-can-spend script.  This script's conditions are satisfiable simply by passing a single push of an element which evaluates to True (e.g. `1` - `0x51`) and that the signature check in `scriptSig` actually has no significance and does not secure the funds at all.

**Edit :**

Actually, looking into this some more, it seems that this transaction is specifically mentioned in [BIP-17](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0017.mediawiki) (which has since been abandoned).  The 20 bytes in `scriptPubkey` is actually the hash160 of the 1-of-1 multisig script itself :

```
51210232abdc893e7f0631364d7fd01cb33d24da45329a00357b3a7886211ab414d55a51ae
```

This is in fact one of the example bip-17 transactions placed on chain by the bip's author.  Should this bip had been accepted, such a transaction would not be anyone-can-spend.  (you can see more details in the bip itself)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself (by trying all substrings of the script).

The correct subscript is this:

`0000 - 51 21 02 32 ab dc 89 3e 7f 06 31 36 4d 7f d0 1c 
0010 - b3 3d 24 da 45 32 9a 00 35 7b 3a 78 86 21 1a b4 
0020 - 14 d5 5a 51 ae END`

In other words, it's frame 03 to frame 06:

`Frame 03: 1(0x51)
Frame 04: 
0000 - 02 32 ab dc 89 3e 7f 06 31 36 4d 7f d0 1c b3 3d 
0010 - 24 da 45 32 9a 00 35 7b 3a 78 86 21 1a b4 14 d5 
0020 - 5a END 
Frame 05: 1(0x51)
Frame 06: OP_CHECKMULTISIG(0xae)`

Contrary to normal subscript generation, this subscript does not go to the end of the script (it doesn't include any part of the public key at all).

I am not sure why this is the case.